# Leaflet padding not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, padding

I'm working on a small Leaflet app and cannot get "padding" working as I expect. In the code below, inside the click handler, I have the line:

```
mymap.fitBounds(myLayer.getBounds(), {padding: [1000, 1000]})
```

which I believe should add a padding to the bounds obtained by myLayer.getBounds(), then the map should zoom to the appropriate level based on both the bounds and padding. However, I see no difference whether I pass in the padding option or not. I also do not see a difference by changing the padding numbers. 
What is currently happening is that when a user clicks on an element represented by a point, it the map will zoom in on that point based on the "maxZoom" value. So if for example, they click on Oakland, the map will display an area around the marker based on "maxZoom"; The "padding" option does nothing.

JS Code

```
//instantiate map
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([39.8283, -98.5795], 3);

//apply layer
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?
  access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
  href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 
  href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, 
  Imagery © 
  <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'all-your-tokens-are-belong-to-me'
}).addTo(mymap);

//cities for markers
var locations ={
  boston: {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-71.05977, 42.35843]},
  oakland: {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.2708, 37.80437]},
  berkeley: {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.2737, 37.8712]},
  london: {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-0.08, 51.509], [-0.06, 
  51.503], [-0.047, 51.51]]]},
  dublin: {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[ [-6.2890, 53.3439], 
  [-6.2653, 
  53.3435], [-6.2603, 53.3356], [-6.2936, 53.3320] ]]},
  glasgow: {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-4.2435, 55.8627]}
};

//define styles
var myStyle = {
  "color": "#ff7800",
  "weight": 5,
  "opacity": 0.65
};

//Create geoJson layer
var myLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {style: myStyle}).addTo(mymap);

//function to add element to geoJson layer
function updateMap(object) {
  myLayer.addData(object);
};

//click on the location's button, add it to the map
$('button').click(function(){
  var region = locations[this.id]
  updateMap(region);
  regionTypeContainer.push(region.type);
  mymap.fitBounds(myLayer.getBounds(), {padding: [1000, 1000]}); // padding 
  //not doing anything
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`padding`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#fitbounds-options-padding) option of `fitBounds()` method is to exclude some parts of the map viewport from the `fitBounds` computation.

If you try to `fitBounds` to a single point (i.e. your GeoJSON Layer Group contains a single Point feature) as you describe, this `padding` option will not change anything., i.e. you would still zoom to `maxZoom` because there is actually no area to fit.

A very simple workaround is to detect the case where `getBounds` returns an "empty" area: `bounds.getSouthWest().equals(bounds.getNorthEast())`

And in that case, you could instead use `mymap.panTo(bounds.getCenter())` for example, so that the map keeps the current zoom level.

```js
var bounds = myLayer.getBounds();

if (bounds.getSouthWest().equals(bounds.getNorthEast())) {
  // Only a single point feature to view.
  mymap.panTo(bounds.getCenter());
} else {
  // Some area to fit bounds to.
  mymap.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/350/